# I need to keep the history data, so user can navigate between a timeline

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am currently developing a database which has three tables modeled like these:

```
procedures (
    id int,
    name varchar,
    desc text,
    created_at datetime
);

validations (
    id int,
    name varchar,
    desc text,
    created_at datetime
);

procedures_validations (
    procedure_id int,
    validation_id int,
    created_at datetime
);
```

And I need to keep de history data, because the user can navigate between a 
timeline. For example:

A procedure named "Procedure 1", on 2019-01-01, has two validations named 
"Validation 1" and "Validation 2". 
After some changes the same procedure "Procedure 1", on 2019-01-05, has three
validations named "Validation 1", "Validation 3" and "Validation 4".

If I select this data group, in a specific date, my result needs to be the 
validations of the procedure at this date. If I change a validation or procedure 
name/desc (update), this information needs to be the same as it was when I 
select data at the period.

In other words, I need to *keep* the history of all validations and procedures.

Duplicate all data (with a diferent date) can be a option but I'm afraid
about performance issues, because there will be a lot of records in these tables
(in number of insertions and duplications).

```
procedures

ID  NAME    CREATED_AT
1   A   2019-01-01 21:00:00
2   B   2019-01-02 21:00:00

procedures_validations

id  PROCEDURE_ID    VALIDATION_ID   CREATED_AT
1   1       1       2019-01-02 21:00:00
2   1       2       2019-01-02 21:00:00
3   1       3       2019-01-02 21:00:00
4   1       1       2019-02-05 22:00:00
5   1       4       2019-02-05 22:00:00


validations

id  NAME    CREATED_AT
1   AA  2019-01-01 21:00:00
2   BB  2019-01-01 21:00:00
3   CC  2019-01-01 21:00:00
4   DD  2019-01-01 21:00:00
```

Comment: Why is "Validation 1" lost? And you don't need to copy older entries, but when doing a `SELECT` for a day not only select the day itself but also all days before.

Comment: My problem is for example on 2019-01-01, I had the validations 1, 2, 3 and on the 2019-02-02 I changed and now I have the validations 1, 4, I have to keep that between the days 2019 -01-01 until 2019-02-02 will use the 1, 2, 3 and not the 1, 4

Comment: So some old validations get "invalid" over the time while others "survive"? Then you could also add a "valid until" column. On the day a validation becomes invalid set that column to today, otherwise the column is null.

Comment: No. The old validations are not invalidated, they are used in a historical way, those who referenced the procedure on that date, should see the validations that were from that date, and not the ones they have today.

Comment: I just needed a word, so don't take "invalidate" to literal. It gets out of scope somehow, doesn't it? Or are there actually two **different** validations e.g. "Validation 1", that just happen to have the same name?

Comment: My data scenario is the one above